# Postgresql how to query a time duration?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-timestamp

In my table **case** ,there are 2 tiemstamp fields looks like:

```
check_in                check_out
"2021-09-07 07:25:00"   "2021-09-08 17:10:00"
"2020-09-25 06:02:00"   "2020-09-27 15:20:00"
"2020-10-26 05:42:00"   "2020-10-29 13:05:00"
```

How can I query the rows that check_out - check_in larger than 2 days,something like:

```
select * from case where check_out - check_in > 2 days ;
```

Then output will be:

```
check_in                check_out
"2020-09-25 06:02:00"   "2020-09-27 15:20:00"
"2020-10-26 05:42:00"   "2020-10-29 13:05:00"
```

Comment: `WHERE check_out - check_in > INTERVAL '2 days';`

Comment: A sidenote: Since "case" is a SQL key word, you should think about renaming this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. You need to give a correct [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) value

```
select * 
from case 
where check_out - check_in > interval '2 days';
```